# Using ST_INTERSECT in a google maps Fusion Table results in Bad Request

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm attempting to see if a lat/long position is contained within certain boundaries on a google map.

I'm displaying my boundaries with a fusion table.

A straight up select from the fusion table results in my polygon data being returned:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT geometry FROM 1NosbtruuU4DH_tC2rtvTkFiMZfPNgL-HWUNx_Kk&key=mykey
```

When adding a WHERE clause with ST_INTERSECT to my query I get an error:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT geometry FROM 1NosbtruuU4DH_tC2rtvTkFiMZfPNgL-HWUNx_Kk&key=mykey WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.8977067,151.1944247),10))
```

The error is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your geographic data is in the column named geometry, not Lat:

Change the Lat in the ST_INTERSECTS to geometry:
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT geometry FROM 1NosbtruuU4DH_tC2rtvTkFiMZfPNgL-HWUNx_Kk&key=mykey WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.8977067,151.1944247),10))

[Example Map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linktoC.html?lat=-33.891093&lng=151.194847&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20geometry%20%20FROM&tableid=1NosbtruuU4DH_tC2rtvTkFiMZfPNgL-HWUNx_Kk&where=%20ST_INTERSECTS%28geometry,CIRCLE%28LATLNG%28-33.8977067,151.1944247%29,10%29%29)

You probably should read [Warren Shen's response to your question in the Google Maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/f19ab93495f2d469#) also.

Comment: Sorry, this was a bad copy/pasting while I was trying out other solutions.  Using geometry results in the Bad Request as indicated in my question

Comment: It does work for me though (in the example in my response).  You do need to put the "WHERE" in the correct place (as Warren Shen observed [here](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/f19ab93495f2d469#) in response to the same question on the Google Maps API v3 group)

Comment: Great thanks, working like a charm now. I was looking at the example provided at https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#auth and didn't consider that the key was being mistaken for part of the query.